# Delete items in custom Listview from listview,on button click

Tags: android, sqlite, custom-lists

I have a custom Listview with remove button in each row.Items in Listview are displayed from a database.On clicking remove button, item from database is deleted.but it is not reflecting in list view.I need to delete the corresponding row of that item.

**CartAdapter.java**

```
public class CartAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

private final String[] pname;
private final String[] price;
private Context cntxt;
 public CartAdapter(Context c,String [] pname,String [] price)
 {

     cntxt=c;
     this.pname=pname;
     this.price=price;
 }
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return pname.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View List;
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)cntxt.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView==null) {
List=new View(cntxt);
List=mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.add2crt_sub,parent, false);

 }
else {
List=(View)convertView;
}

 Button button=(Button)List.findViewById(R.id.remove);
 button.setTag(position);
 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        int position = (Integer)v.getTag();
        SQLiteDatabase mydb=cntxt.openOrCreateDatabase("addcart",Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        String pnam = pname[position];

        mydb.execSQL("DELETE FROM add2cart WHERE pnme ='"+pnam+"'");

        Cursor cr = mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM add2cart", null);
        String [] pname = new String[cr.getCount()];
        String [] price = new String[cr.getCount()];

        int i = 0;
        while(cr.moveToNext())
        {
            String name = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("pnme"));
            String prprice = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("prate"));
            pname[i] = name;
            price[i] = prprice;
            i++;
        }

        CartAdapter cart=CartAdapter.this;
        add2cart.adlstvw.setAdapter(cart);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    });
 TextView nametxt=(TextView)List.findViewById(R.id.prdt_nme);
 final TextView pricetxt=(TextView)List.findViewById(R.id.prdt_rate);
 final TextView totltxt=(TextView)List.findViewById(R.id.prdt_totl);
 final EditText edittext=(EditText)List.findViewById(R.id.prdt_qnty);
 edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String s1=pricetxt.getText().toString();
        String s2=edittext.getText().toString();
        int i1=Integer.parseInt(s1);
        int i2=Integer.parseInt(s2);
        int res=i1*i2;
        totltxt.setText(Integer.toString(res));
        if (s2.matches("")) {

            edittext.setText("");

        }


    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub




    }



    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});

 nametxt.setText(pname[position].toString());
 pricetxt.setText(price[position]);

    return List;
}


}
```

Comment: post the error or the crash

Comment: can you please share full error or exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all you need a reference to the Context class to open the database

```
 SQLiteDatabase mydb=CartAdapter.this.openOrCreateDatabase("addcart", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

above code is wrong

you have to pass a context to the database class which i cant see in the above line... so correct me  if i am wrong

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "(": syntax error: DELETE FROM add2cart WHERE pname=button.setTag(position
```

quiet clean from the above line there is a syntax error in below code

```
mMydb.execSQL("DELETE FROM add2cart WHERE pname=button.setTag(position)");
```

i guess the correct code could be

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int position = (Integer)v.getTag();
 //this will give you the position of the data been clicked
 // how extract the data item from the list at the position
 // for eg that data is in pname vriable
    SQLiteDatabase mydb=cntxt.openOrCreateDatabase("addcart",Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    String pnam = pname[position];
    mydb.execSQL("DELETE FROM add2cart WHERE pnme = '"+pnam+"'");
    notifyDataSetChanged();


}
});
```

also you have to delete a item from you list String []pname to reflect the changes in listview you should better use List pname as deletion is better in List data structure

Comment: are you sure that particular column is  deleted from database?

Comment: The  change in  database is not reflecting in listview.Is there any thing wrong in my code in deleting from my list.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing CartAdapter.this with activity context you have passed in constructor of your adapter class.

replace

```
SQLiteDatabase mydb=CartAdapter.this.openOrCreateDatabase("addcart", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

with

```
SQLiteDatabase mydb=cntxt.openOrCreateDatabase("addcart", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

Comment: Your query is wrong. I guess there should be 'pname[position]  ' instead of ' button.setTag(position)'

Answer (score 0):

The whole design of the OnClickListener is wrong. It doesn't make any sense to open your database every time the user clicks a button.

You should copy paste the following line to the adapter's constructor:

```
 mydb=cntxt.openOrCreateDatabase("addcart",Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

keep mydb a local variable, you may call it mMydb for correct code convention.

Then, in the onClick() just leave the following line:

```
mMydb.execSQL("DELETE FROM add2cart WHERE pname=button.setTag(position)");
        notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Additionally, as @dragon born suggested - you should use the encapsulated activity context so just add it to the adapter's context and use it.